Failed to find provider info on one Android 12 device
I have two the same devices with Android 12 where I have application A which creates content provider and application B which tries to read data from that provider.
On one device, application B can access data from that provider, but on the other device it is not accessible.
I receive cursor == null when I try to query contentResolver and I see in logcat:
ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for *name*
Does anybody have any suggestion what should be the problem?
I have defined this way the provider in manifest.xml:
<application>
        <provider
            android:name=".content_provider.MyContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.content_provider"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
         />
    </application>

this is in client app B manifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
                     tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission"/>
<queries> 
   <package android:name="com.example.content_provider" /> 
</queries>

   <queries>
        <provider android:authorities="com.example.content_provider" />
    </queries>

In code I use:
   val AUTHORITY = "com.example.content_provider"

public static final String URI_FOR_CHANNEL_PARSING = "content://com.example.content_provider/channel";

this is how I query the content:
 Uri channelUri = Uri.parse(URI_FOR_CHANNEL_PARSING);
 ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
  Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(channelUri, null, null, null, null);

EDIT: is there a possibility that client app B can not access content provider because cursor is not closed or someone else is reading it's content?

What error do you get on the device that doesn't work? Are you sure they're exactly the same device? I've encountered problems with the same hardware from different carriers or with different OTA updates.

@KevinKrumwiede in log i see ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for name. cursor is null. Yes, the same hardware

On one device, the app can access data from that provider, Which app? Should we guess?

android:readPermission="com.example.PROVIDER_PERMISSION"/> That is not needed. First try without. And where did you define that <permission ...?

@androiddev Not just the same hardware, the same carrier and everything. Example: one time Sprint pushed an update to their Galaxy Tabs that broke the HEADSET_PLUG intent so apps could no longer receive it. The same nominal Android version update on other carriers' Galaxy Tabs did not break the intent. Sprint never acknowledged wrongdoing and my company had to replace 300 tablets.

@blackapps my client app that needs data from content provider.
I defined permission in manifest above 

Does this answer your question? Failed to find provider info error

@Maveňツ no, I am still facing issues. I have added   but it is still not working.

You should of course also post the code with the query. Do the query also on the app with the content provider.

@blackapps I updated the question with code how I query the data

can you post app and build gradle

In the manifest of the client app -that does not have the provider- add a <queries> with <package android:name="the.other.app" />.

should the name be the package of app or package of content provider or name of content provider?

Package of content provider.

it did not help me. I updated the post with new code
